# Generating Polymatrix games from GAMUT

Tags: java, game-theory

I'm trying to generate Polymatrix Games from the [GAMUT](http://gamut.stanford.edu/) java library.

```
    try {
        PolymatrixGame polyGame = new PolymatrixGame();
        
        polyGame.setParameter("players", nbOfPlayers); //nbOfPlayers = 3L;
        polyGame.setParameter("actions", nbOfActions); //nbOfActions is a Vector<String> with three entries: each equal "2".
        polyGame.setParameter("graph", "RandomGraph");
        
        polyGame.setParameter("graph_params", new ParamParser(new String[] {"-nodes", "" + nbOfPlayers, "-edges", "" + 3, "-sym_edges", "1", "-reflex_ok", "0"}));
        polyGame.setParameter("subgame", "Chicken");
        polyGame.setParameter("subgame_params", new ParamParser());
        
        polyGame.initialize();

        polyGame.doGenerate();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: Unable to generate polymatrix game (subgame Chicken)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

I've been digging through the source code but I couldn't find the source of the error. The error message itself isn't really useful either.

Ultimately, I'm trying to generate a random Polymatrix game with given number of players and given number of actions for each player.

Comment: Have you had any success using the command line?

Comment: Yes. _java -jar gamut.jar -g PolymatrixGame -players 3 -actions 2 -graph RandomGraph -graph_params [-nodes 3 -edges 3 -sym_edges 1 -reflex_ok 0] -subgame Chicken -subgame_params []_ succesfully generates a game. The java code above seems to represent this command exactly, but doesn't seem to work regardless.

Comment: k, I ask because I too used GAMUT to generate random games. After a long struggle with the API, I simply coded up an adapter that would facilitate calling the jar from command line. I integrated this in my application by calling the jar using `Runetime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ....")`.

Comment: I will try to play with that. However, I will be needing the PolymatrixGame object in my application. Your workaround only generates a file, right?

Comment: Yes, it generates a file which I then parse into my own implementation of a bimatrix game. Do you really need the `PolymatrixGame` object, or do you really just want a 3D array of payout values?

Comment: As you most likely know yourself, games get really big really fast because of their exponential growth in function of number of players ($n$) and number of actions for each player ($s$). The size is something like $ns^n$. A PolymatrixGame is called a succinct game because its input can be represented polynomially ($s^2n^2$). This is done by using a graph-like datastructure. I need PolymatrixGames with a lot of players and/or actions, Using the n-dimensional array of payout values is therefore unrealistic as its size would be exponential, the game wouldn't fit in memory.

Comment: Additionally, I don't want to re-invent the wheel and create my own datastructures, as I trust the numerous datastructures in GAMUT work well as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging through source code and debugging, 
I have found that what is causing the `NullPointerException`.

GAMUT assumes that you demanded the generation of a game using the command line. It stores the arguments of the command in a `String` array  variable named `gArgs` in the `Global` class.

```
  // -- Original command line
  public static String[] gArgs;
```

When a `PolyMatrix` game is generated, a method from the `GameOutput` class is called that changes the `gArgs` array of `String`s into a normal `String` which is then stored in the relevant `PolyMatrix` object. The mentioned method is given below.

```
public static String arrayToString(String[] args, String sep)
{
StringBuffer buff=new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
    buff.append(args[i]);
    if (i!=args.length-1)
    buff.append(sep);
}

return buff.toString();
}
```

It is called as follows in the `Game` class. `GameOutput.arrayToString(Global.gArgs, " ")`

If `Global.gArgs` is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` will be thrown for obvious reasons. This is exactly what happens in the code example in the original post because `Global.args` is never set.

**Quick solution**: Set `Global.gArgs` to something meaningless like `Global.gArgs = new String[]{""};`

**Best solution**: Actually set `Global.gArgs` to the array of `String`s containing the arguments you'd give if you were to generate the game from command line.
Something like `Global.gArgs = new String[]{"-players", "3", "-actions", "2", "-graph", "RandomGraph", "-graph_params", "[-nodes 3 - edges 3 - sym_edges 1 -reflex_ok 0]", "-subgame", "Chicken", "-subgame_params", "[]"}`

(The example given for the 'best' solution may or may not differ slightly from the actual value of `Global.gArgs` if the game were to be actually generated from command line).

It is strange, however, that simple games like PrisonersDilemma and Chicken do not require the `gArgs` variable to be set.

Comment: the link to your "user friendly GAMUT API" is dead. Is that project still alive?

Comment: Not really. I deleted the repo and decided I should -in depth- learn how GAMUT really works. I'd love to see how other people work with GAMUT but haven't had the opportunity yet.